# Why block-level elements behave like this?

Tags: css

```css
.wrapper.one {
  outline: 1px solid;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper.one > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(44, 204, 55);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper.two {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper.two > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(55, 44, 204);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper.three {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper.three > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(204, 44, 55);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- change font size-stuff-->
<div class="wrapper one">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- closeopen tag-stuff -->
<div class="wrapper two">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- comment out-stuff -->
<div class="wrapper three">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div><!--
  --><div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example you see there is a white line between the two direct children in each wrapper.  I found 3 suggestion on the web how to fix it that did not work (in example) also the use of inline-block elements (whyy???).

I found out that this not work to clear all space between them.

```
div {
  margin: 0;
  }
```

But use of asterisk (fetch all) will work to clear all space between them.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  }
```

**I know:**

- A block-level element start on new-line
- A block element width is 100% if not set

**I don't know:**

- why asterisk works and div not..
- why starts on new-line even if line is clear

Any advice is very welcome :-)

Comment: It's because of the 20px margin on the last P inside the div. That also explains why `*` does the trick: it removes that margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `*` selector works because the margin is caused by the `p` element, which is captured by that selector (but not with `div`).

You can use `p { margin: 0; }`, as in the example below.

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper.one {
  outline: 1px solid;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper.one > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(44, 204, 55);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper.two {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper.two > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(55, 44, 204);
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper.three {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper.three > div {
  /* select all div with direct parent .wrapper  */
  background-color: rgb(204, 44, 55);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- change font size-stuff-->
<div class="wrapper one">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- closeopen tag-stuff -->
<div class="wrapper two">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- comment out-stuff -->
<div class="wrapper three">
  <div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div><!--
  --><div>
    <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
      <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        <p><a>A </a><b>B </b><code>C </code><del>D </del><em>E </em>
        </p>
  </div>
</div>
```